# Subclassing with inner classes, serializing only outer

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, inner-classes

I have two questions concerning inner classes. First one is about extending and overriding the methods and attributes of the inner classes in a subclass.
Suppose I have a super class with an inner class that contains derived attributes.

```
class ASuper implements Serializable {  
    // Attributes, methods  
    int a;  
    int b;  

    class Inner {
        // Derived attributes, methods
        int c;
        int d;
        public calculate() {
            c = a + b;
            d = a * b;
        }
    }  
}
```

And I want to subclass ASuper in such a way that some of the attributes in the inner class of the subclass are given new values and some are the same.

```
class ASub extends ASuper {
    int e;

    class Inner {
        int f;
        public calculate() {
            // int c = same as in the super class
            f = a^b - e;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand how to do this. Do I have to override the definition of **int c** in the **ASub.Inner.calculate()** or can I refer to super?

The second question is about serialization. The objects of outer classes must be serializable but the corresponding objects of the inner classes need not be, since all their attributes are derived from the attributes of the outer objects.How can I achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but when things get complicated, I generally avoid using inner classes and pass an instance of `ASuper` to `Inner` explicitly in the constructor.

Comment: Your inner class does not contain any 'derived attributes'. The inner class of your derived class doesn't give any new values to any attributes of the first inner class. The attributes of your inner classes are not derived from their outer classes. Unclear what you're talking about. Or asking.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using wrong terminology. By "derived" attributes I mean attributes that are _calculated_ from other attributes. Like attributes `c`, `d` and `f` in the example above.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you misunderstand idea of inner classes.
Your `ASub.Inner` class isn't related to `ASuper.Inner` at all.
You can't access to its field or something.

In fact inner class it is pretty simple thing. It is just same as regular class with two exception:

- it can access to instance fields of outer class (because it have hidden reffernce to instance of outer class)
- fields and methods of outer class is visible to it even if they marked as `private`

About your later question. Class must be marked as `Serializable` in case you will serialize it. Inner class isn't exception. Only one thing to note if your inner class is serializable its outer class must be too because of hidden reference in inner to outer.

Comment: Thank you.    
I guess I'll just have to use derived attributes as if they were normal attributes. Or I'll have to reformulate my question so that the problem becomes clearer.

Comment: Attributes can be *derived* if you use inheritance. Inner classes is not related to inheritance.

Comment: Well, what is the proper term for attributes that are _calculated_ from other attributes in the same class? I don't remember the proper term. For example, if the `paintComponent` method uses certain values that are calculated from attributes in a class. So instead of calculating them at every call to `paintComponent` it can be convenient calculate them once and store the result.